# Azure work item search not showing results for all users

Tags: azure, tfs

I have the Azure Code Search and Work Item Search extensions installed.  We are running Azure DevOps Server 2019.  I have some users that get 0 results on a search, where I can search the same thing and get many many results.  This is not a permission issue.  I have given them identical permissions as myself.  However the same searches bring up no results for them.  Also I am an administrator, I'm wondering if this is a permission issue.  Also the search is installed on a seperate server than our application teir.

Comment: Which content do you search? If you search a work item, could you let the users to check the work item to see whether they can access the work item. Please check the FQA below to see whether it helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/faq-search?view=azure-devops-2019. Also, you can ask the users who can't see search result to capture the Fiddler trace to see whether there is any useful information.

Comment: I checked and they do have access to those work items.  I will try a fiddler and see if that helps.

Comment: They do have access to see the work items I return in a search.  However when they do a search they get 0 results.

Comment: Have you captured the fiddler trace? Is there anything useful?